# Linux : Give permission to an user

Tags: linux, image, file, drupal, permissions

I have a folder with this permissions : **-rwxrwxr-x** and when i'm adding a file in this folder the permissions are : **-rw-rw-r--**
I would like to change it to **-rwxrwxr-x** but not only this file but all files that will be added

thank you in advance

Edit: Im on Drupal 7, and when i'm trying to load an image his permission is 664 and i can't use image style.

I tried to change his permission to 775 and it's work but the next uploaded images will be again at 664

Comment: what command have you tried so far?

Comment: I doubt that is possible. The executable bit is nothing that is controlled by the file permission mask logic of shells like bash. I assume you will have to implement some own logic based on something like either a file alteration monitor to which you attach a permission modification logic, or some alternate way of saving/creating files, for example a wrapper around the touch or copy command.

Comment: On my dev server it's works correctly but not on the integration server

Comment: check if your folder have as owner apache (or nginx user) something like www-data.www-data , and check htaccess configuration about files/ folder , you can get some information , maybe drupal restrict by default other directories